ModuleNotFoundError: from airflow.providers.mongo.hooks.mongo import MongoHook
I have already installed the apache-airflow-providers-mongo package. It appears in the pip list, and all three dependencies are installed correctly. However, in the code, I still encounter a ModuleNotFoundError from the airflow.providers.mongo.hooks.mongo package.
My Code look like this:
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.providers.mongo.hooks.mongo import MongoHook
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pyodbc

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")

...


Error is attached in Screenshot:


Did you restart Airflow after the install?

Yes I have already restarted airflow . @EladKalif

Are you sure you installed the package in the right environment?
